# Cannot run my own Java Package

Tags: java, package

I want to learn to write my own packages so I'm not also relient on an IDE, which I feel I have became. The problem is I cannot figure out how to run my own package, or what the proper method is to run your own package.

Here's a resource I used to learn some basics: http://javaworkshop.sourceforge.net/chapter3.html

Here's my current file structure:

```
Main.java
/src
 projectaqua/
  GameFrame.java
/classes
 projectaqua/
  GameFrame.class
```

I ran the command in the root directory of the project:`javac -d ./classes/ ./src/projectaqua/*.java`

I originally created a Main file in the /src/projectaqua directory and attempted to run the file. I was given this error:

```
Main.java:1: error: package projectaqua does not exist                               
import projectaqua.GameFrame;
```

I tried running the application in the /classes/projectaqua directory when compiling the Main file with the package, which gave me a class not defined error.

This compiled my package, the problem I'm facing is I don't understand how you are supposed to import your own package to run it, and where would the file to run the package be?

From what I've learned in school, when writing a GUI application we create a class that has a main function in it to instantiate the frame, and that's it's only job. Where would this be in this structure?

Intuitively it seems that file would be outside of the src files, but I feel like that removes the purpose of the src files. I haven't found anything useful on stackoverflow to this topic, if you do or have please point me in that direction.

More source code:

GameFrame Class:

```
package projectaqua;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{

    private int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    private int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
    private String title = "Project Aqua";
    private boolean isVisible = true;

    public GameFrame()
    {

        // Basic Window Defaults
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setTitle(this.title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Content Pane junk
        // Will be added

        setVisible(this.isVisible);

    }

}
```

The Main class

```
import projectaqua.GameFrame;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GameFrame launch = new GameFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: Java is a pretty coupled-to-IDE language and ecosystem, so I would recommend viewing IDE-less-ness as more of an educational exercise. But at least make sure you're using a tool like Maven so you don't have to be dealing with classpaths spanning dozens of lines.

Comment: So would the class path be the reason why I'm having issues?

Comment: Post a complete [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) - in particular of the java source - and I can help you from there.

Comment: Yes, you're probably not specifying it, or doing so incorrectly. Maven is massive overkill when trying to learn the basics.

Comment: @djechlin - `Java is pretty coupled to IDE-language and ecosystem`? That is simply not true. IDE's just make Java development much, much easier.

Comment: @djechlin There is my full source code..

Comment: @RyanDawkins where is Main.java?  your directory structure does not reflect its existence

Comment: I just added it, it is in /src/projectaqa. Really you can ignore it, I don't know where to put the class with the main function.

Comment: I copied your two source files and ran command as you posted and it compiled, so some info you have here is probably incorrect.  And I certainly can't ignore it since it's the thing that's not compiling.

Comment: Wait did you try *running* the file or *compiling* the file?  To be clear as far as I can tell it looks like you can't compile yet.

Comment: I can compile in the root directory, using javac -d ./classes/ ./src/projectaqua/*.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now see your problem.

In your question you were not clear that you had trouble running v. compiling.  Had you posted this error trace it would have been immediately clear to me what your problem is:

```
 unrollme-dev-dan:projectaqua Dan$ java Main
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: projectaqua/Main)
```

Also note that had you Googled `NoClassDefFoundError` would have found this.  The moral here is:  understand and research your exact error.

Anyway

```
unrollme-dev-dan:classes java projectaqua/Main
```

is what you want.  Notice the change of directory.  I never bothered to understand why, has to do with relationship between package hierarchy and file structure hierarchy.

Java had two choices when designed:  Assume the thing you are talking about is in the global package (yuck!) or try to guess what package it is in.  It treats any folder below your working directory as packages.  So even though it found a `Main` class in the directory from which you were running it did not find a `Main` class in the namespace corresponding to the directory `.` i.e. the global one.

When you run from one directory up and tell it to run something in `projectaqua/` it is now looking for classes starting with `projectaqua`.

Alternately if you run

```
unrollme-dev-dan:projectaqua java projectaqua.Main
```

It looks for the right thing.

Comment: So will this only work when in the classes folder? It works when I try java projectaqua/Main when in directory /classes, but when I try: classes/projectaqua/Main it does not work.

Comment: @RyanDawkins see my edit for fuller explanation of how this works

Answer (score 0):

try this command at the root of your project

```
javac -cp ./classes -d ./classes ./src/projectaqua/*.java
```

Also make sure both your Main.java and GameFrame.java has `package projectaqua;` at the beginning